# Setting middleware for specific controller in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, middleware

I want to create a middleware that checks for a private access key header and add it to a specific `ApiController` in ASP.NET Core.

The only ways I found were using `app.useMiddleware()` or checking whether or not the request URL contained the controller route but that's not what I want to use as it seems pretty inefficient.

How else can I achieve this?

Comment: The middleware pipeline is **global** to any given ASP.NET Core application - you **cannot** have middleware only for some specific controllers ....

Comment: @marc_s so does that mean i need to use the url path checking method?

Comment: "checks for a private access key" - sounds like you need to create a [custom authentication scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#authentication-handler), then enforce it on the controller with [Authorize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-7.0#selecting-the-scheme-with-the-authorize-attribute) attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You can use `app.UseWhen()` method to apply a middleware
  conditionally based on the request path. For example,

  `app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(“/api”), appBuilder => { app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>(); });`
- You can use `[MiddlewareFilter]` attribute to specify a middleware
  pipeline class on your controller or action. For example,
  `[MiddlewareFilter(typeof(MyPipeline))] public class MyController : Controller { … }`
- You can use `MapWhen()` method to branch the request pipeline based
  on a predicate. For example, `app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey(“PrivateAccessKey”), appBuilder => { app.UseMiddleware<MyMiddleware>(); });`